# Access with SharePoint Designer to SP Site created by Provider Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I created a Provider hosted app. I can access the list by the url like: `https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/site/lists/mylist/`

So far so good. Now I want to create a Workflow for the list `https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/site/lists/mylist/`. But when I try to connect to the list with SharePoint Designer it denies me access.

SharePoint Designer is enabled.

Is there a way to activate the SharePoint Designer access for the created site?

Is it also possible to enable this by VS Deployment (only for this site)?

Or is that never possible to connect to this site with SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the site, https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/site, and not the list directly. Once connected, then you can see the list and add a workflow.

Comment: H i tried this it connect to the Site and to the list. Booth give med the Same denied message :(.